# SKLabelNode doesn't render anything

Tags: ios, objective-c, sklabelnode

I have a strange problem. I am using a `SKLabelNode` in one of my projects. It does not show me any errors, but nothing appears either. What am I doing wrong?

```
@implementation GameScene
{
  SKLabelNode *myTitle;
}

- (void)didMoveToView:(SKScene *)view {
  myTitle = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Arial"];
  myTitle.position = CGPointMake(175 ,5);
  myTitle.fontSize = 80;
  myTitle.fontColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  myTitle.text = @"SMASH";
  [self addChild:myTitle];
}

@end
```

Comment: Did you present the scene? do other elements are shown? what is the background color of your scene?

Answer (score 0):

Nodes should be added to the scene root node:

```
[self.rootNode addChildNode:myTitle];
```

Or to other nodes in the root node tree.